# Scrollbars not working in android project

Tags: android

Scrollbars not working. I have given the scrollbars as parent view, but still, my screen is not scrolling. I am not able find out the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Featured Image -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sandwich"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/sandwich_picture_content_description"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <!-- Tabbed Toolbar + Pager -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:elevation="6dp"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    tools:ignore="NewApi" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:elevation="6dp"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have given the scrollbars as parent view, but still, my screen is not scrolling. I am not able to find out the problem. I have given the scrollbars as parent view, but still, my screen is not scrolling. I am not able to find out the problem.

Comment: Put scrollview in another layout

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the FrameLayout with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout such that this Layout becomes the direct child of your Scrollview.

Also, instead of Parent view as ScrollView, Add a RelativeLayout as the parent followed by ScrollView.

**RelativeLayout -> ScrollView -> LinearLayout -> FrameLayout.**

Comment: Not working, i changed still not working in my layout.

Comment: Check the upated ans.

Comment: Not working, I think the problem coming due to tab layout and viewpager. On textview its working fine.

Comment: Following my ans, make the height of ScrollView as wrap_content and try once and keep the parent layout width nd height to be match_parent.

Comment: Not working brother....check this - https://github.com/ajitpradhan925/Sandwich_Club_New